# How to specify a java.util.Function that returns another generic type with type covariance?

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I would like to write a method that takes a list and a `Function` returning another generic type, say `Optional`. A concrete example for such a method would be one that applies the function to all elements in the list, and returns a list of all elements that didn't result in an empty `Optional`.

To the best of my understanding, here is how I would write out this method:

```
public <I, O> List<O> transform(List<I> list, Function<? super I, Optional<? extends O>> function) {
  List<O> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (I element : list) {
    Optional<? extends O> optional = function.apply(element);
    if (optional.isPresent()) {
      result.add(optional.get());
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

The reason I used wildcard arguments for `Function` are as follows:

- I don't really care if the input to the `Function` is exactly `I`. It should be fine to pass anything that takes a parent type of `I`.
- The `Optional` that the `Function` returns doesn't have to be exactly `O`. It should be fine to return an `Optional` of a subtype of `O`.

Let's test this by first defining two simple types:

```
public class Animal {}
public class Cat extends Animal {}
```

Now suppose we're starting with a list of `Cat`s:

```
List<Cat> catList = new ArrayList<>();
```

According to the two points I made about `transform` taking wildcard arguments above, I would like to transform this list into another list of `Animal`s using the following method:

```
public Optional<Cat> animalToCat(Animal cat) {
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

This indeed works when I pass a method reference to `animalToCat`:

```
List<Animal> animalList = transform(catList, this::animalToCat); // works!
```

However, what if I don't directly have this method reference available, and would like to store the method in a variable first before passing it to `transform` later?

```
Function<Animal, Optional<Cat>> function2 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList2 = transform(catList, function2); // does not compile!
```

Why does the line resulting in `animalList` compile, but the one resulting in `animalList2` doesn't? Through trial and error, I figured out that I can indeed make this compile by changing the type of the variable I'm assigning my method reference to to any of the following:

```
Function<Animal, Optional<? extends Animal>> function3 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList3 = transform(catList, function3); // works

Function<Cat, Optional<? extends Animal>> function4 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList4 = transform(catList, function4); // works

Function<? super Cat, Optional<? extends Animal>> function5 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList5 = transform(catList, function5); // works
```

So it seems to be okay to assign the `animalToCat` method reference, which is clearly one taking an `Animal` and returning a `Optional<Cat>`, to other `Function` types. However, taking the existing `animalToCatFunction2` and assigning it to the other types *also* fails:

```
animalToCatFunction3 = animalToCatFunction2; // does not compile!
animalToCatFunction4 = animalToCatFunction2; // does not compile!
animalToCatFunction5 = animalToCatFunction2; // does not compile!
```

I'm very confused as to why it would be okay to treat the `this::animalToCat` method reference in a way that would make it seem like the returned `Optional<Cat>` is a covariant type, but that behavior suddenly breaks as soon as the reference is assigned to a variable with a specific type. Is my definition of `transform` wrong?

Comment: I'm sure you need to use `Function<? extends I, ...`, but I don't know why your first `animalToCat` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [STU's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49942519/974531) for the underlying reason.

To get your example to work, you need to help the Java type system a bit by using more type parameters:

```
<A, B, C extends B, D extends A> List<B> transform(List<D> list, Function<A, Optional<C>> function) {
    List<B> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (D element : list) {
        Optional<C> optional = function.apply(element);
        if (optional.isPresent()) {
            result.add(optional.get());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Since the dynamic sub-type of the incoming list can be different to the outgoing one, it's useful to add another sub-type to the example:

```
class Dog extends Animal {}
```

Then the example code is:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Animal> animalList = transform(dogList, this::animalToCat);

Function<Animal, Optional<Cat>> function2 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList2 = transform(dogList, function2);
```

EDIT: Modified the type constraints a bit to make it work with the example in the comment as well:

```
Optional<Animal> catToAnimal(Cat cat) {
    return Optional.empty();
}

Function<Cat, Optional<Animal>> function2b = this::catToAnimal;
List<Animal> animalList2b = transform(catList, function2b);
```

Comment: Your version of `transform` indeed works for the example I posted! However, when I'm varying the used transformation function, I'm getting something else that's odd.

Further introducing:
`public Optional<Animal> catToAnimal(Cat cat) { ... }`

The following then doesn't compile:
`Function<Cat, Optional<Animal>> function2b = this::catToAnimal;`
`List<Animal> animalList2b = transform(catList, function2b); // does not compile!`

However, the same works going from animal to animal, from cat to cat, or as you showed already from animal to cat. Why?

Comment: @smf68: The case with `function2b` does not work, because `transform` gives the function inputs of type that are a sub-type of `Animal`, but not necessarily a sub-type of `Cat`, as per the type constraints. They happen to be objects of type `Cat` with `catList`, but Java doesn't expand generic functions like C++ templates; instead, Java tests applications against constraints.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are coupling the A/D relationship with the B/C relationship, which is true in my example, but shouldn't generally be the case. If you make them completely separate, I believe your example works for all my use cases!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason this does not compile:

```
Function<Animal, Optional<Cat>> function2 = this::animalToCat;
List<Animal> animalList2 = transform(catList, function2);
```

whereas this does:

```
List<Animal> animalList = transform(catList, this::animalToCat);
```

is that *bare* method references have a type that is not representable in the user-visible type system.

You can think of `this::animalToCat` as having the "magic" type `Function<contravariant Animal, covariant Optional<Cat>>`, but as soon as you convert to the user-defined type `Function<Animal, Optional<Cat>>` you lose the information about the variance of raw functions themselves.

At that point, you can't assign a `Function<Animal, Optional<Cat>>` to a `Function<Animal, Optional<? extends Animal>>` for the same reason you can't assign a `Function<Optional<Cat>, Animal>`to a `Function<Optional<? extends Animal>, Animal>`.

C.f. `Function1[-T1, +R]` in Scala.